# How to resolve incorrect user input requesting a specific wiki page

Tags: c#, user-input, wikipedia-api

I am creating a Reddit bot which accepts user input, and then attempts to fetch a table from the specified wikipedia page and post it to reddit.  The user will specify a professional boxer's name, and the bot will try to find that boxer's wikipedia page and post his professional record table.

The problem is that this is relying upon unreliable user input.  Many boxers are not from English speaking countries and their names contain non-English characters.  This leads to a lot misspellings of names, which ultimately result in a failure.

I have created a method which attempts to resolve commonly requested names:

```
public string FighterNameFixes(string fighter)
    {
        if (fighter.ToLower() == "julio cesar chavez" || fighter.ToLower() == "chavez")
        {
            return "Julio César Chávez";
        }
        else if (fighter.ToLower() == "julio cesar chavez jr." || fighter.ToLower() == "julio cesar chavez jr"
                  || fighter.ToLower() == "julio cesar chavez, jr" || fighter.ToLower() == "julio cesar chavez jr.")
        {
            return "Julio César Chávez Jr.";
        }
        else if (fighter.ToLower() == "roy jones jr" || fighter.ToLower() == "roy jones, jr"
                        || fighter.ToLower() == "roy jones jr." || fighter.ToLower() == "rjj")
        {
            return "Roy_Jones_Jr.";
        }
//continue for every boxer that has ever lived
```

If I cannot find a match, and the reply process fails, I log an exception and continue.  I would like to find a more programmatic approach to solve this problem.  Is there a library or API which would help me resolve misspellings like this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Comment: Thanks dave, this looks promising.

Comment: I would look into the search API, and make sure you are following Wikipedia redirects which probably handle most common misspellings.